# PHPMailer when linked with AJAX doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, phpmailer

Note: I have read other questions and they did not help.

So I first tested on my localhost with ajax and PHPMailer and it worked perfectly as I received the email and with ajax it said email sent.

When I uploaded to a live site, it stopped working. And I'm sure the connection is solid because when I take away AJAX and just put it as a PHP page it works. But, when its an external file with AJAX it doesn't (on a live website)

Here is the AJAX Code:

```
<script>
    var ajax = {
        isSubmiting: false,
        send: function() {

            if(ajax.isSubmiting == false) {
                ajax.isSubmiting = true;

                var userName = $("input[name=name]").val();
                var userEmail = $("input[name=email]").val();
                var userComments = $("textarea").val();
                var currentBusiness = $("input[name=business").val();
                var currentWebsite = $("input[name=website]").val();

                    ajax.SetText("Sending...");
                    $.post("sendmail.php", {
                        name: userName, email: userEmail, comments: userComments, business: currentBusiness, website: currentWebsite
                    }, function(data) {
                        if(data == "true") {

                            ajax.SetText("Sent!");  

                            $.get("sent.html", function(sentData){

                                $("#content").html(sentData);

                            });

                        } else {
                            ajax.SetText("Send mail");

                            $.get("unsent.html", function(sentData){

                                $("#content").html(sentData);

                            });

                            console.log();
                        }

                        ajax.isSubmiting = false;
                    });

            }
            else alert("You can only send 1 email at a time");
        },
        SetText: function(text) {
            $("input[type=button]").val(text);
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here is the PHPMailer script (sendmail.php):

```
<?php

    $result = "";
    $error = "";

    if(count($_POST) > 0) {

            $message=
            'Full Name: '.$_POST['name'].'<br />
            Email:  '.$_POST['email'].'<br />
            Message: '.$_POST['comments'].'<br />
            Current Website: '.$_POST['website'].'<br />
            Business Name: '.$_POST['business'].'<br />
            ';

            include "phpmailer/class.smtp.php";
            include("includes/class.phpmailer.php");

            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
            $mail->isSMTP();
            //Enable SMTP debugging
            // 0 = off (for production use)
            // 1 = client messages
            // 2 = client and server messages
            $mail->Host = localhost;
            //Set who the message is to be sent from
            $mail->setFrom('info@coherenthub.com', 'Coherent');
            //Set an alternative reply-to address
            //$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
            //Set who the message is to be sent to
            $mail->addAddress('coherenthub@gmail.com', 'Coherent');
            //Set the subject line
            $mail->Subject = 'Contact Form';
            //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
            //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
            $mail->MsgHTML($message); 
            //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
            $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

            if (!$mail->send()) {
                die("There was an error sending the email.");   
            } else {
                die("true");    
            }


        }

?>
```

Does anyone have a clue as to why this wouldn't be said. Just to reiterate, on a single PHP page without ajax and with the script in the  it works fine on a live and local server. BUT, when I put it in an external file and link with AJAX, it only works in local server but not on live. Any answers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Define "Doesn't work". Pretty much any ajax system tends to want a JSON-format return value, an you're not doing that. You're also not making any use of PHPMailer's error reporting features, and not surprisingly that means you can't tell what's going on.

Comment: @Synchro I did enable error reporting but I cant exactly view them, not in the console, not on the page, or anything. Is that because its an external file? And by doesn't work I mean it says it failed to send and doesnt send.

Comment: If you can see that it says it failed to send, you can see error output. Try simply saying `die("There was an error sending the email.".$mail->ErrorInfo);` for a start.

Comment: @Synchro Ok thanks, let me try that

Comment: @Synchro So i did that and in jQuery did alert(data) but it returned blank for some reason.. Am I doing something wrong? And when I said it said failed to send I meant thats what I wrote with the "unsent.html" if it doesnt return true.

Comment: You don't have to rely on jquery output - use your browser's web inspector to view responses directly. Anything you echo from your PHP script will be visible in there, including PHPMailer debug output if you enable it with `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`.

Comment: @Synchro and this will work even if the phpmailer script works on a different file?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't care.

Answer (score 0):

You have used relative paths in your scripts. When calling from Ajax, make sure the paths are getting translated to correct ones.

You can check console to check Ajax call is working correctly and then server error log to verify there are no php errors.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13707260)

Comment: Oh, OK, sure. Was just providing suggestions to get the error reported by system. Will use question comments next time.